# Dynamically created script not executing

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am appending a script tag, along with a bunch of other html, to my current document, retrieved from an ajax call. For some reason the script is not running

```
//Response handling function
function(responseText){
    document.getElementById('reportContainer').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin',responseText);
}
```

An example of `responseText`'s contents:

```
<h2>You are <em class="won">victorious</em>!</h2>
<h3>Earnings</h3>
... 
<script>
    alert('dgd');
</script>
```

All the html is getting applied to the document, including the script, but it is not running, I don't get this alert popping. What may be causing this?

Comment: Why don't you use `innerHTML` ?

Comment: @RashminJaviya i tried it, no luck.

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery :)

Comment: @RashminJaviya because I don't like it :D

Comment: Scripts injected via markup strings are intentionally ignored to avoid XSS. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML#Security_considerations. The contents of the `<script>` will have to be `eval`ed to be executed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml

Comment: @php_nub_qq did you check the following answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following snippet and call the function as

```
var newEle = document.querySelector("#reportContainer");
exec_body_scripts(newEle);
```

Function

```
exec_body_scripts = function(body_el) {
  // Finds and executes scripts in a newly added element's body.
  // Needed since innerHTML does not run scripts.
  //
  // Argument body_el is an element in the dom.

  function nodeName(elem, name) {
    return elem.nodeName && elem.nodeName.toUpperCase() ===
              name.toUpperCase();
  };

  function evalScript(elem) {
    var data = (elem.text || elem.textContent || elem.innerHTML || "" ),
        head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] ||
                  document.documentElement,
        script = document.createElement("script");

    script.type = "text/javascript";
    try {
      // doesn't work on ie...
      script.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data));      
    } catch(e) {
      // IE has funky script nodes
      script.text = data;
    }

    head.insertBefore(script, head.firstChild);
    head.removeChild(script);
  };

  // main section of function
  var scripts = [],
      script,
      children_nodes = body_el.childNodes,
      child,
      i;

  for (i = 0; children_nodes[i]; i++) {
    child = children_nodes[i];
    if (nodeName(child, "script" ) &&
      (!child.type || child.type.toLowerCase() === "text/javascript")) {
          scripts.push(child);
      }
  }

  for (i = 0; scripts[i]; i++) {
    script = scripts[i];
    if (script.parentNode) {script.parentNode.removeChild(script);}
    evalScript(scripts[i]);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't execute when you push it into the DOM in this way. Can you use jQuery? It will execute it:

```
$('#reportContainer').append('<script type="text/javascript">alert(123);</script>');
```

Comment: OP has not mention `jquery` tag in answer

Comment: I thought `insertAdjacentHTML` is doing exactly that - converting string to DOM objects? I don't use jQuery

Comment: Then you won't be able to do it as the browsers don't execute the script. Under the hood, jQuery does. It most likely parses the string you're attempting to insert and eval()s it. Can you use jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

What you get from ajax call is plain text or XML that can be inserted into DOM as HTML fragment, but all javascript code is explicitly forbidden for security reasons. There are plenty of choices to workaround this situation - from extracting  part in the responseText and using eval method (not recommended, bad practice) to using of jQuery.load method.